# How to properly get resource Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, resources

In my project i currently have a setup using eclipse

[image]

But when i try to load the file "bg.png" by calling
`getClass().getResource("/res/bg.png")` or  `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/bg.png")` I get a NPE

Can anyone tell me whats happening here? I never really thought there was much difference between how both methods locate their files

TIA

Comment: Are you sure, that returned object is not null?

Comment: @agad When using ```getClass().getResource("/res/bg.png")``` but when using ```getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/bg.png")``` its fine

Comment: But are you sure, that this object is not null? Pls try `InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/bg.png"); if (stream == null) throw new NullPointerException("Stream is null");`

Comment: @agad oh you were right, both are null. What could be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getClass().getResource[AsStream]()` uses the class loader to load resources: the same mechanism as the one used to load class files based on the classpath.

So, to be able to load the resource, it must be in a jar file or under a directory that is part of the classpath. That is not the case here.

Move the `res` directory to the `src` directory: the file will then be in an Eclipse source directory, and Eclipse will "compile" it by simply copying the file to its bin/classes/whatever destination directory, which is in the classpath when running the application.

Comment: So its not actually possible to load the file if its outside of the src folder?

Comment: It's possible to load a resource if the resource is in the runtime classpath. Putting the file in src is a way of making eclipse copy it to the destination directory, which is in the runtime classpath.